# closing search box by clicking outside the box

Tags: javascript, css

I need help to edit this search box model:

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);

/* entypo */
[class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
  color: #C0C0C0;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: pink;
}

#container {
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.entypo-search:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  left: 0px;
}

#form {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: width .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .55s ease;
  -o-transition: width .55s ease;
  transition: width .55s ease;
}

form {
  position: relative;
}

input {
  width: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;  
  /* margin-top: 3px; */
  line-height: 30px;
}

.entypo-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}

#form:hover {
  width: 200px;
}

#form:hover form input {
  width: 200px;
}

#form form input:focus, 
#form form input:active{
  outline:none;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="form">
    <form action="#" class="entypo-search">
      <fieldset><input id="search" placeholder="Search" /></fieldset>
    </form>  
  </div>
</div>
```

The search box expands and collapses on hover, but there is a problem if the user, for example, clicking on the suggestion dropdown, then the search box does not hover anymore and the search box collapse.
I want to change its behavior, so it will close/collapse only when clicking with the mouse outside the box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented some javascript which looks at when you hover the `#form` and then when you click on the `.container`. I also removed the `:hover` css and made that the class which I toggle on and off in the event listeners.

```js
// closes the form when clicking its container.
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("form").classList.remove("active");
});

// This stops the closing of the form when clicked
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

// open the form on mouseover
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.getElementById("form").classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);

/* entypo */

[class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
  color: #C0C0C0;
}
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px;
}
body {
  background-color: pink;
}
#container {
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.entypo-search:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  left: 0px;
}
#form {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  right: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: width .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .55s ease;
  -o-transition: width .55s ease;
  transition: width .55s ease;
}
form {
  position: relative;
}
input {
  width: 0px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  /* margin-top: 3px; */
  line-height: 30px;
}
.entypo-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
}
#form.active {
  width: 200px;
}
#form.active form input {
  width: 200px;
}
#form form input:focus,
#form form input:active {
  outline: none;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="form">
    <form action="#" class="entypo-search active">
      <fieldset>
        <input id="search" placeholder="Search" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, BTW the code "* {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;border: 0px;outline: 0px;box-shadow: 0px;}", can be only applied to elements under div "container"?

Comment: @Dorel Sorry, I'm not 100% certain what you are asking there.. If you want that CSS to be applied to all elements inside the `#container` div, then change it to `#container * {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;border: 0px;outline: 0px;box-shadow: 0px;}` - i.e. add a space.

Comment: yes this is what I meant, for some reason, it is not working for me, anyway I solved it somehow.

Comment: @Dorel just be careful with `*` it's  a real menace and hard to debug once your CSS starts to pile up!